# UITableViewCell trailing item moves when setting accessoryType

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a `UITableView` with custom cells, and in those cells I have a `UITextField` aligned to the right using trailing constraints.

My problem is that when I set an `accessoryType` like `.checkmark`, my `UITextField` moves to let some space for the accessory.

I'd like to have my textfield staying at the same place whether I have a checkmark or not.

Here is the default look of the cell:
[image]

When tapping on the cell, I add a checkmark:
[image]

Here is the code setting the checkmark or not:

```
cell.accessoryType = selected ? .checkmark : .none
```

Here are the settings of the trailing constraint:
[image]

Comment: Could you provide some videos or gifs of this problem, please?

Comment: @lorenzo Please add more information to clarify what's your current code/storyboard state at the moment.

Comment: @igdev I've added pictures and some more details thanks

Comment: @Lorenzo - I have a complete explanation and answer, if this question gets re-opened.

Comment: Check Apple's docs for [UITableViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell), you'll see that the cell's `.contentView` frame changes when the `.accessoryType` is set. If you search, you will find many solutions including using your own "checkmark showing/hidden" view as the cell's `.accessoryView`. A much easier option is to constrain your text field Trailing Constant to 0 (or maybe a small value for "padding"), set `.accessoryType = .checkmark` on ***ALL*** cells, and then set the cell's `.tintColor` to `.systemBlue` or `.clear` to show/hide the checkmark.